# Bake Alembic and export as glTF or FBX with animation

Tags: blender, alembic, fbx, gltf, cinema-4d

I have an Alembic animation of a flower growing. I am attempting to export it as glTF or FBX with the animation intact, but without success. My end goal is to be able to use the animated file in the browser, or in Spark AR.

[image]

I have tried using Nitrobake, but the resulting object does not animate. Have not been successful in finding other directions to try, and when consulting more experienced friends, they also seem at a loss.

[image]

I have also looked at https://vimeo.com/78684377, a video regarding baking Alembic to point caches, but I do not believe it is what I need - Or, I simply did not understand it properly.

I am using C4D R21 but happy to try Blender too, or other software that could do the trick.

Comment: Alembic, as well as mdd and pc2, support mesh objects that deform over time, that is, they can use different mesh data each frame. Like what is used for fluid or particles and where a point cache becomes related. Fbx supports a static mesh that can have an armature that deforms the mesh as it moves. I believe gltf is the same. I don't know if you will have any luck converting that animation to fbx or gltf. I believe there is an alembic importer for unity, look for the same in spark, unless unity to spark is an option.

Comment: Alembic works in Unity using the Alembic importer, but does not work exported as an iOS app. Thanks for the explanation!